# Python finds nonexisting character in file, replaces with nonintended character (encoding issue with non-English characters)

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I created a script in python to fix the wrongly-encoded Turkish characters in an .srt file.
e.g. 'ý' replaced by the correct character, 'ı'.

I open the file (read), iterate over the lines to `.replace('ý', 'ı')`, then write the new set of lines to a new file with `'w', encoding='utf8'`.
It works great the first time! The issue is that each iteration messes up the fixed character by replacing it with 2 other characters. Can provide more info if needed!

Part of input:

```
yakýn deðillerdi, ama
bir þeyler yapmak istedim
```

Output the first time around:

```
yakın değillerdi, ama
bir şeyler yapmak istedim
```

Output the second time around:

```
yakÄ±n deÄŸillerdi, ama
bir ÅŸeyler yapmak istedim
```

Output the third time around:

```
yakÃ„Â±n deÃ„Å¸illerdi, ama
bir Ã…Å¸eyler yapmak istedim
```

And it gets worse every time it runs through. Thoughts? If I had to guess, the characters I'm finding ('ý') match with the ('ı') already in the file, then replace it with ('ı') which is wrongly-encoded into ('Ä±')? It's also not a systematic change every time (see second-->third iteration) so I'm stumped.
I'm a bit of a newbie so please excuse any "obvious" knowledge I might not have!

edit:
The code, as requested:

```
import os

directoryPath = 'D:\\tv\\b99'

fileTypes = ['.srt']

fullFilePaths = []

def get_filepaths(directory, filetype):
    """
    This function will generate the file names in a directory
    tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each
    directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself),
    it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
    """
    filePathslist = []
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            # Join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            # include only the specific file types, except their hidden/shadow files
            if filepath.endswith(filetype) and not filename.startswith('.'):
                filePathslist.append(filepath)  # Add it to the list.
    return filePathslist

n=0
def replaceChars(folderAsListOfPaths):
    """
    This function takes a list as argument, containing file paths.
    The file is read line by line, and for each of the "special" 
    characters in Turkish that get encoded incorrectly, the appropriate 
    replacement - shown below - is made, and the existing file is overwritten.
    ('ý'->'ı') / ('Ý'->'İ') / ('þ'->'ş') / ('Þ'->'Ş') / ('ð'->'ğ')
    The filenames are printed when the replacement is done, for confirmation.
    """

    # read file line by line
    file = open(folderAsListOfPaths[n], "r")
    lines = file.readlines()

    newFileContent = ''
    for line in lines:
        origLine = line
        fixedLine = origLine.replace('ý', 'ı')
        fixedLine = fixedLine.replace('Ý', 'İ')
        fixedLine = fixedLine.replace('þ', 'ş')
        fixedLine = fixedLine.replace('Þ', 'Ş')
        fixedLine = fixedLine.replace('ð', 'ğ')
        newFileContent += fixedLine
    file.close()

    newFile = open(folderAsListOfPaths[n], 'w', encoding='utf8')
    # print(newFileContent)
    newFile.write(newFileContent)
    newFile.close()

    cleaned_name = folderAsListOfPaths[n].replace(directoryPath, '')
    cleaned_name = cleaned_name.replace('\\', '')
    print(cleaned_name)


for type in fileTypes: 
    fullFilePaths.extend(get_filepaths(directoryPath, type))
# filled the fullFilePaths list with the files

print('Finished with files:')

for file in fullFilePaths:  # for every file in this folder
    replaceChars(fullFilePaths) # replace the characters
    n+=1    # move onto the next file
```

Comment: Please add your the code you have written.

Comment: @Jortega Done! Thank you for the heads-up.

Comment: You are opening the files in a default encoding.  The default is the result of `import locale;print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.  The files are probably not in that encoding.

Comment: Try `open(folderAsListOfPaths[n],'r',encoding='cp1254')` which is a Turkish encoding and skip all the replacements.  Write the UTF-8-encoded files to another location so you don't process same files over-and-over.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Oh! That did work. The issue now is that when it runs into one that isn't encoded in cp1254, it throws an error. (I want the code to run this way for a particular use case unfortunately) I'll figure that out though, thanks!

Comment: @all, I guess... does anyone know why the code initially "found" and "replaced" the characters? I would think it still wouldn't find-replace with characters I didn't put in the code.

Comment: When you read a UTF-8 file as the wrong encoding such as cp1252, it converts each byte of the multi-byte UTF-8 encoding into multiple cp1252 single-byte characters.  Then you encode *those* into multibyte UTF-8, and decode back to single-byte characters again...

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Error Description: The source encoding is `iso-8859-9`.

***Option 1: Read File in Correct Encoding***

```
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='iso-8859-9') as f:
   # Read file
```

***Option 2: Handle Specific Subtitles for Modifications***

Use this custom made `fix_turkis_encoding` to fix encoding:

```
original_subtitle = 'yakýn deðillerdi, ama\nbir þeyler yapmak istedim'

def fix_turkis_encoding(s):
    source_encoding = 'iso-8859-9'
    destination_encoding = 'utf-8'
    return s.encode(destination_encoding).decode(source_encoding).encode(source_encoding).decode(destination_encoding)

# yakýn deðillerdi, ama
# bir þeyler yapmak istedim
print(fix_turkis_encoding(original_subtitle))
```

Comment: No, just read the file with the correct encoding in the first place :)

Comment: Much preferable indeed! Thank you @MarkTolonen

Comment: Also worth noting that ISO-8859-9 (a.k.a Latin5) and Windows-1254 (a.k.a cp1254) as mentioned in a comment are similar but different Turkish encodings.  The latter is more likely the correct one on Windows, which looks like what the OP is using. Both work on the sample, but there are some minor encoding differences.